# Calculating the nth combination of a set of sequential numbers

Tags: arrays, graph-theory, combinatorics

I have a number `n` that my program uses to represent a list of natural numbers of size `n`:

```
[0,1,2] // n=3
[0,1,2,3,4,5] // n=6
```

The lists always begin with `0` and their elements appear in sequential order with no numbers skipped. The last element is always `(n-1)`.

Now, I need to get the unique pairs of elements for these arrays. So I wrote an algorithm that takes `n` as an input, and returns an array of unique pairs of elements from its counterpart above.

```
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]] // n=3
[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5],[4,5]] // n=6
```

In this implementation, elements cannot pair with themselves (e.g. `[0,0]`). The pair `[1,2]` is considered equivalent to `[2,1]`, so only the former would appear.

However, since the pairs have a consistent ordering and follow a basic pattern, I suspect that there is some numeric formula I can use to calculate their *values* directly—without programmatically creating a list of them.

What I want is a function `f(n,i)` that would give me the values in the `i`th pair in the array of pairs for `n`, for example:

```
f(3,2) => [1,2]
f(6,8) => [1,5]
```

Alternatively, it'd be fine to have two functions: One, `g(n,i)`, that returns the first pair-element and another, `h(n,i)`, that returns the second. Like this:

```
g(3,2) => 1
h(3,2) => 2
g(6,8) => 1
h(6,8) => 5
```

Is there a formula that can calculate those numbers?

Note: I am not looking for an algorithm to generate the combinations arrays. I have that already. I want to avoid generating array combinations and simply calculate the combination values directly, numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @shawnt00 for the basic idea of inverting the triangular number; I used `x = (sqrt(8*i + 1) - 1)//2` as the triangular root, which worked out.

```py
def find(n, i):
    m = n * (n - 1) // 2
    i = m - i - 1
    t = (sqrt(8 * i + 1) - 1)//2
    return (n - t - 2, n - 1 - (i - t * (t + 1) // 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f(n, i):
    m = (n - 1) * n / 2 # error check i <= m
    i = m - i # zero-based index
    t = floor((sqrt(8 * i + 1) - 1) / 2)
    r = i - t * (t + 1) / 2
    [n - t - 2, n - r - 1]
```

The trick is to count backward from the end. Otherwise you're basically looking to find the triangular number preceding `i` and calculating relative to that.

Wikipedia has many properties on triangular roots including the formula used above to derive the triangular root.

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer but I'll get back to this and test.

Comment: It's definitely onto something, although its output includes selfsame elements like [1,1]. Going to fiddle with it...

Comment: @kcsquared Found the ultimate solution but upvoted you for pointing in the right direction.